# What filesystems allow repositioning the beginning of a file?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Typical filesystems, and the POSIX interface, only allow a file to be resized at the end. Typically the size of a file "on disk" after it has been closed is equal to the offset of the read/write position when it was closed. Seeking before closing is also known as "repositioning the end-of-file."

A file that contains a queue of data would be more efficiently represented by an operation to remove the beginning of the file. The on-disk allocation blocks at the beginning could be freed, and needless copying minimized.

Is this directly supported by any common filesystem format and/or operating system? What kind of interface is used to do so? (For example, a Linux `fcntl` selector.) I'm pretty sure I've heard of this kind of thing in practice.

Comment: Close-voters… asking for a Linux API essentially makes this a "question about programming." If you feel bad inadequate about not being able to answer, go sulk somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Linux **does** have an interface that does what you are requesting.   It is the FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE flag to fallocate.  It is supported by btrfs, ext4, and xfs (possibly others) on modern kernels.   Although the fallocate interface allows you to specify byte offsets and lengths, in practice the COLLAPSE_RANGE call will only work if the offset and the length is a multiple of the file system block size.

For more information please see the Fine Manual for the fallocate(2) system call: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html

Comment: Thanks! The older `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` flag there also solves the practical problem, albeit without shifting the offsets. I haven't tried it, but the manpage suggests it reliably works with bytes in addition.

Comment: It works with bytes by zeroing them.   If you are trying to release space back to the file system, it will only do this in aligned 4k chunks.

Answer (score 4):

No. Not in the Unix world, at any rate.

If you look inside DBMS or Unix(ish) file system internals, they can easily truncate or extend datasets at the beginning, at the end, or anywhere in the middle. But they don't export that functionality; it's not part of the Unix API heritage or the POSIX standard, so any "truncate at beginning" or "extend at beginning" APIs would be non-standard ("proprietary").

The marginal utility of such functions is also unclear. Who would use them? How often?

Unix files (flat sequences of bytes/characters) have proven themselves simple and effective for application code, but a poor foundation for layered data structures. Twenty five years ago that statement was debatable; today it's just an observed historical reality.

Unix developers used to argue "all things can be reduced to files" and "we can ace random access through clever seeking." Those claims never quite worked out, however. Unix never, for example, matched the random-access record management prowess of minicomputer and mainframe operating systems (e.g. DEC RMS, IBM ISAM and VSAM). And while those implementing file systems, queues, tries, relational databases, and object stores do occasionally drop contents into files, and they use files for sequential operations like logging, but they rarely depend on character streams as their low-level format. Instead they use structures like B-trees and hash tables to directly manage disk blocks, memory segments, and other underlying resources.

Character streams belong with tables, documents, and objects--abstractions suitable for client applications. If you want a queue, consider using existing middleware (e.g. RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, REDIS, some DBMS manager) that already has this covered. If you must build it yourself, you'd probably wouldn't build it atop a simplistic character stream abstraction. So while truncate/extend at beginning is potentially useful for some things (log trimming instead of segmented log rotation, e.g.), it's unlikely to be a Big Win for most data structure implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've seen is file formats that indicate that data has been "deleted" and then the deleted space can be reused after. This typically only works with fixed-length record formats such as DBF, and requires a little more memory in order to maintain both indices of deleted records for reuse as well as the order of the records within the file.

Comment: If deleted blocks can be entirely zeroed out, this is just as efficient as the OP's proposed scheme since Unix FSs tend to use a sparse representation where zero blocks aren't stored.

Comment: @larsmans: Unfortunately turning a non-sparse file into a sparse file is not cheap, even if the bytes in question have been zeroed out.

Answer (score 1):

Repositioning the beginning of the file is probably not a good idea. That would risk to confuse processes having file descriptors open on that file and expecting it to be correctly seekable, i.e. having a predictable offset.

If your main goal is just to save disk space, there are several approaches.

If you have ZFS support and enable deduplication, blocks previously used to store the data of the beginning (or any part actually) of a file can be freed just by overwriting them with zeroes.

Under Linux, you should also be able to free parts of a file store in a file system supporting sparse files (most of them) by using the `fallocate` system call and passing it the [FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) flag. Solaris provides the similar `fcntl` command [F_FREESP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2241/fcntl-2/index.html). Whether `fallocate` or `fcntl` will work efficiently or at all is implementation dependent though.

Alternatively, If you run an OS that doesn't provide a `fallocate` or equivalent functionality but supports `ZFS` (eg: [FreeBSD](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=35415)), and/or if deduplication is not an option because you have not enough RAM to dedicate to it, a lightweight alternative would just be to enable compression on the file system.